# How can I create a certain amount of edit texts staying next to each other programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a number of edit texts programmatically without using XML, but I faced some problems while trying this out. Here is a piece of code:

```
private void createEditText(int l, int topMargin){
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams vlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(vlp.width, vlp.height);
    layoutParams.setMargins((vlp.leftMargin + l) - vlp.width - vlp.height - 25, topMargin, vlp.rightMargin, vlp.bottomMargin);
    final EditText newEditText = new EditText(this);
    newEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittext);
    newEditText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.addView(newEditText);
}

private void numberOfEditTexts(){
    String[] words = Answers.answers[getCurrentLevel()].split(" ");
    int l = 0, topMargin = 450;

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++){
        createEditText(l, topMargin);
        l += editText.getLayoutParams().width + 5;
        if(i == 0) topMargin -= 560;
    }
}
```

The first function creates an edit text and I send 2 parameteres to it, of which the topMargin is the variable that defines the altitude coordinates of the edit text. So the problem is that this edit text will appear differently on different devices because of their screen sizes.
How can I fix it? How can I avoid setting the position manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the screen width and length. Use the percentage of screen size as your margin size.

to get the screen size by pixels,

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Your margin can be some percentage of the height: like 5% or 10% of the screen height. Then it is adjustable.

Comment: You mean to get the value of the screen size and send it to setMargins() function as the replacement for topMargin? I've tried this, but setMargins() function receives only integers as its parameters, therfore I can't take the percentage of height variable.

Comment: when you call createEditText(int l, int topMargin), instead of pass in a fixed int, try to pass in the screenHeight*5/100, something like this.